# css - div overlap using nested lists

Tags: html, css

This simplified html/css shows that divs following nested lists don't seem to get placed correctly. Why isn't the gray (#eee) div below the end of the lists? (It has a clear:both) It seems to be below the "One, Two, Three", but not the "Alpha, Beta, Gamma".

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body     { padding:0; border:0; margin:0; }
#bodydiv { outline:1px dashed black; }
li       { width:100px; height:50px; outline:1px dotted blue; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bodydiv">
  <div style="outline:1px dotted black;">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three
        <ul>
          <li>Alpha</li>
          <li>Beta</li>
          <li>Gamma</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both; height:20px; background:#eee;">--First--</div>
  <div style="width:100px; height:50px; background:#fdd; outline:1px dotted red;"></div>
  <div style="width:100px; height:50px; background:#dfd; outline:1px dotted red;"></div>
  <div style="width:100px; height:50px; background:#ddf; outline:1px dotted red;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QzRTT/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning a specific `height` to the `li` that contains the nested `ul`, so it's not rendered the way you want. Just declare a minimum height `min-height` instead of a fixed `height` for that element, and you can get rid of `clear:both`, it does really nothing here:

```
li {
    width:100px;
    min-height:50px;
    outline:1px dotted blue;
}
```

See it here: http://jsbin.com/zowusegu/2/edit/

Comment: Oh, rats (I spent a long time on this). I knew clear:both wasn't appropriate here. Thanks so much.